# MSMQ Lost First Message

Tags: msmq

In MSMQ first message is lost not receive in queue, but after that we system is in normal form, Can any one please explain.

Simple Code

public class MSMQExample{

```
 private MessageQueue GetQueue(){

    MessageQueue _queue=new MessageQueue(@”.\Private$\Test");
    return _queue;
 }

 public void SendMessage(){
         MessageQueue queue=GetQueue();
         Message msg = new Message();
         msg.Body ="Test"
         queue.Send(msg);
}
//Call this method in Application_Start event in new Task.
public void StartQueue(){
    MessageQueue queue=GetQueue();
    Message msg=null;
    while(true){
       msg=queue.Receive();
       //Processing Code
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide us with some more info please! Maybe some code that you use to receive messages with. Messages don't just disappear in MSMQ.

Comment: If the message cannot be sent then "queue.send(msg)" will throw an exception which you can catch and display. You can use performance monitor to track the number of messages in the queue and the system as a whole which can be useful for understanding if/when messages are created and consumed.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to mark the messages as `Recoverable`.
By default, `MSMQ` messages are only held in memory, but `Recoverable` messages are backed to disk to enable reliable `MSMQ` messaging.

```
using System.Messaging;
Message recoverableMessage = new Message();
recoverableMessage.Body = "Sample Recoverable Message";
recoverableMessage.Recoverable = true;
MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(@".\$private\Orders");
msgQ.Send(recoverableMessage);
```